# Permission in Python to write to MySQL database?

Tags: python, mysql, permissions, mysql-python

I think I have a permission issue with python and mysql. Here is my test code test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb

#change the host, user, passwd, and db below as necessary
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="username", passwd="password", db="database")

cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * from table")
a = cur.fetchall()
print "pre values"
print a

cur.execute("insert into table values(3)")
db.commit

cur.execute("SELECT * from table")
a = cur.fetchall()
print "updated values"
print a

cur.close()
db.close()
```

The username/password definitely works when I execute mysql in shell and try to insert values, so let's say I have values of 1 and 2 already in my table. This tries to write a 3 to it and commits it.

This prints out

```
pre values
(('1',), ('2',))
updated values
(('1',), ('2',), ('3',))
```

When I try to run the exact same script again, it gives the exact same output. So despite showing that it definitely added into the database, it did not add into the database. When I went to mysql after in shell and looked into the table it indeed did not insert a new value.

Every single place I've looked up just tells me over and over again to have db.commit, which I do so I'm now very confused.

EDIT: I also went to the location of the database on my computer (everything is on my local machine) and chmod'd 777 to the database and the folder containing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *call* `db.commit`. You forgot the parentheses at the end:

Use

```
db.commit()
```

instead of

```
db.commit
```

---

The reason it *seemed* to work is this: While you operate on your DB connection (before you commit), your changes get applied to the DB *session*. So your objects are updated in your session, but the changes are not written to the DB yet (objects in this state are usually called *dirty*).

When you subsequently query the DB again, you will see the changes from your session, even though they haven't been written to the DB yet. Once you `commit()`, all the changes from your session get actually written to the DB.

However, if you [`close()`](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#Connection.close) a connection with a dirty session, an implicit rollback will be performed:

> The connection will be unusable from this point forward; an Error (or
>   subclass) exception will be raised if any operation is attempted with
>   the connection. The same applies to all cursor objects trying to use
>   the connection. Note that **closing a connection without committing the
>   changes first will cause an implicit rollback to be performed.**

Comment: OH MY GOD I AM THE DUMBEST PERSON EVER THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Why did the commit still show something though? Or did it just show something because of the insert

Comment: You're welcome. And I wouldn't say you're dumb, you at least were able to to describe your problem clearly and provide a complete, self contained example that made it easy to spot the mistake. You wouldn't believe how many people fail at that ;-)